# Sql server deny drop view to role

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2008-r2, sql-server-2012

I use `SQL Server 2008 R2` and want to deny drop any view to developer role.

How can add deny permission for drop any view to this role.

By database Trigger can prevent drop any view for all user.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem here is that the deny permission applies to the following securables:

- Synonyms
- Tables and columns
- Views and columns

So you could use:

```
USE dbName
GO
DENY DELETE TO [developerRole]
GO
```

The problem is that I assume that you will want some of the developers to be able to drop items, this will prevent anyone in the developer role from dropping any of the above securables.  You could instead apply this permission directly to the user, but if you want them to be able to drop tables or columns, but not views, then it won't work either.

Another method would be to move all your views into a separate schema, then deny the user DELETE on that schema:

```
USE [dbName]
GO
DENY DELETE ON SCHEMA::[viewsSchema] TO [developerRole]
GO
```

The problem here is that it's messy and not really the best use of a schema, not really an option I would go for.

I think the best option really is a trigger, if it really is just one user you can do the following:

```
CREATE TRIGGER noViewDrop
ON DATABASE
FOR DROP_VIEW
AS
IF USER_ID() = USER_ID('Bob')
    BEGIN
        PRINT 'Bob Can''t Drop Views';
        ROLLBACK
    END
```

This means that Bob can't drop any views in the database, but can drop any of the other securables listed above.  If you want to apply this to a database role rather than an individual user, simply use the IS_ROLEMEMBER() function like so:

```
CREATE TRIGGER noViewDrop
ON DATABASE
FOR DROP_VIEW
AS
IF IS_ROLEMEMBER ('developerRole') = 1
    BEGIN
        PRINT 'Members of the developerRole Can''t Drop Views';
        ROLLBACK
    END
```

Meaning anyone in the developer role will be caught by the trigger when dropping views, but if they need to drop a column they will still be able to do this.  Anyone who is not in the developerRole will still be able to drop views.

Answer (score 0):

Trigger

```
CREATE TRIGGER NO_DROP_VIEW
ON DATABASE
FOR DROP_VIEW
AS
PRINT 'Dropping VIEWs are not allowed'
ROLLBACK
```

Comment: I want to deny permission to special user. I said in my question that, I do't want to use database trigger.

Answer (score -1):

To deny drop view you can simply include `DENY DELETE`

```
use Your_Database
GO
DENY DELETE TO [SQLUserTest]
GO
```

When user is denied `DELETE` permission, that user is no longer able to drop or delete any object in that database.